# How do I prevent access to records that belong to a different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

How do I prevent accessing a specific set of records based on a session variable?

i.e. I have a table of items with a user_id key, how do I filter access to the items based on user_id. I don't want someone to be able to access /items/3/edit unless that item has their user id against it (based on session var)

update:
I am using the answer suggested by @fl00r with one change, using find_by_id() rather than find() as it returns a nil and can be handled quite nice:

```
@item = current_user.items.find_by_id([params[:id]]) || item_not_found
```

where item_not_found is handled in the application controller and just raises a routing error.

Comment: I think the question is a bit vague, but have you tried using [named scopes](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html)? And something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restrict access by fetching items through your `current_user` object (`User` should `:has_many => :items`)

```
# ItemsController
def edit
  @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

where `current_user` is kind of  `User.find(session[:user_id])`

**UPD**

Useful Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/178-seven-security-tips, TIP #5

Comment: in this case user can type direct path in address bar: /artilces/1/edit

Comment: @Meduza, yeah this is what I was originally trying to avoid - this solution works for me though, I just use a 404 if not found.

Comment: @Meduza, do you understand what `current_user.items.find(params[:id])` means? It will throw an error if `item` doesn't belong to `current_user`

Comment: @floor, But there more request: Fetch all items and then get one record

Comment: @Meduza there is only one requet. `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user_id=XXX and id=XXX`

Answer (score 2):

You can check access in show/edit/update method:

```
def edit
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  restrict_access if @item.user_id != current_user.id
  ....
end
```

and add restrict_access method, for example in application_controller

```
def restrict_access
  redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access denied"
end
```